# how to use Reflection API to look for field variables or methods - Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm which will allow me to marshalling a Java class into XML without creating an object of that class ( this is the problem, and it's very complex to do with the tools I have ). I have to read the data from a log file and transform that into a XML one.
A sample from the log file:

```
2206:org.powertac.common.RandomSeed::4::init::TariffMarket::0::fees::-6239716112490883981
2213:org.powertac.common.msg.BrokerAccept::null::new::1
2214:org.powertac.common.msg.BrokerAccept::null::new::1::null
2216:org.powertac.common.RandomSeed::5::init::org.powertac.du.DefaultBrokerService::0::pricing::8741252857248937781
2226:org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification::6::new::1::CONSUMPTION
2231:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::new
2231:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::withValue::-0.5
2232:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::setTariffId::6
```

The pattern for the log file is:

```
<id>:<class_name>::<order_of_execution>::<method_or_new>::<arguments>
```

Thus, I want to translate the following line into an `XML`:

```
2231:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::new
```

will be written as:

```
<org.powertac.common.Rate>
    <rate>0</rate>
</org.powertac.common.Rate>
```

I have the parser to give me the values so I have access to that data. The idea I came so far is to use the [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) `Java` API to the dirty job for me, otherwise I had to pretty much create a symbol table to accomplish what I want. I know I can use the `Reflection` API to look up for a symbol:

```
private static void printMembers(Member[] mbrs, String s) {
    out.format("%s:%n", s);
    for (Member mbr : mbrs) {
        if (mbr instanceof Field)
        out.format("  %s%n", ((Field)mbr).toGenericString());
        else if (mbr instanceof Constructor)
        out.format("  %s%n", ((Constructor)mbr).toGenericString());
        else if (mbr instanceof Method)
        out.format("  %s%n", ((Method)mbr).toGenericString());
    }
    if (mbrs.length == 0)
        out.format("  -- No %s --%n", s);
    out.format("%n");
    }
```

One example what I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
2231:org.powertac.common.Rate::7::withValue::-0.5
```

Then I would take the `class` name, `org.powertac.common.Rate`, use `Class`:

```
 Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
 printMembers(c.getMethods(), "Methods");
```

to return me the method `withValue` and it's  arguments, so I could programmatically create the following `XML` code:

```
<org.powertac.common.Rate>
   <withValue>-0.5</withValue>
</org.powertac.common.Rate>
```

Also, one of the potential complications if when the `method` or `class` takes an `object` for example, so there should have some sort of recursive approach to produce the correct result.
I'm totally new with the `Reflection` API, so I was wondering if someone knew better than me how to accomplish that.
Thanks

****Updates***
I do have access to the classes, and I can instantiate them, however, I need to find out the right arguments, so this is a more complex task.

Comment: I deleted my original comment because I saw you need to convert from the log file format to XML. Xstream is only going to work if you can convert from the object to XML.

Comment: I don't see why you need to use reflection for converting the log file to XML. That looks like a simple transformation.

Comment: If I had a new to create the object, then it will be easy ... I have to accomplish that without creating the object

Comment: Reflection would only appear to be needed for converting the XML back to a Java object.

Comment: @SteveD: I had a rough idea of how could I have a way to look up to all the variables and methods of the class, and Reflection seemed to give the that information.

Comment: But why do you need to look up the class if you have the info in the log file?

Comment: @SteveD: `XStream` would unmarshalling that back to an object for me. However, there is a little complexity on it: `2226:org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification::6::new::1::CONSUMPTION` for example, it's given as a `["1", CONSUMPTION] but `TariffSpecification` takes a `Broker` and a `Enumerator` into the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear: do you have classes to store the data in, or don't you? If you don't already have classes that represent the data, and don't want to create them, then reflection isn't going to help you.

Instead, I suggest just using [JAXP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-frame.html) to produce your output. Create a `Document`, add `Element` children to it, then use a serializer to generate the output. Google for "DOM tutorial" to find some examples.

Comment: I do have the classes, but how do I create them? If you read the problem a little more careful, you will be able to understand the complexity ...

Comment: @philippe - OK, you have classes, but why do you need to populate them? You seem to be creating complexity here.

Comment: As I mentioned, that's just a rough idea, I'm totally open for a more easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have created sample application just to create structure for following class

```
class Rate
{
private double minValue;

public Rate withValue(double value)
{
    minValue = value;
    return this;
}

public double getValue()
{
    return minValue;
}
}
```

Following class creates `Rate` using `Reflection` and then call `withValue` API

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException,
        IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException
{
    Class<?> class1 = Class.forName("Rate");
    Object obj = class1.newInstance();
    for (Method m : class1.getMethods())
    {
        if (m.getName().equals("withValue"))
        {
            Class<?>[] parameterTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.getParameterTypes()));
            Object methodArgs[] = new Object[parameterTypes.length];
            for (Class<?> parameterType : parameterTypes)
            {
                // Here I know there is primitive and double but your logic
                // should check for each and every type
                if (parameterType == Double.TYPE)
                {
                    double value = 0.5;// Value to be passed
                    // directly using 0 since I know only element is there
                    methodArgs[0] = value;
                }
            }
            // Now Creating Rate here directly to check but you may have to
            // again cast to generic object
            Rate rate = (Rate) m.invoke(obj, methodArgs);
            System.out.println(rate.getValue());

        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not quite there yet, but close: For example: `2226:org.powertac.common.TariffSpecification::6::new::1::CONSUMPTION` takes a `Broker` object, but it's only represented by "1" (`Broker(String id)`).

Comment: You  need to use same idea and create object of. Broker reflectively using `parameterType`  which will have its class invoke constructor.